# Download a CSV file from FTP with Ruby on Rails and Update Existing Records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, ftp

I'm trying to download a CSV file from an FTP server and if the record exists I want to update that record and not create a duplicate. To give a little more context - I'm trying to upload a group of orders from an FTP folder into my Rails app. There is a new file every hour - sometimes the orders in a certain drop contain duplicates from the previous drop to prevent one from slipping through the tracks or on occasion the order has been updated by the customer (change in qty, change in address, etc.) w/ the next drop. So my question is if the order is purely a duplicate with no changes how can I skip over those orders and if a record has been changed how can I update that record?

Ruby on Rails 5.1.4 - Ruby 2.4.1

Thank you!

The code below is from my model:

```
class Geek < ApplicationRecord
require 'csv' 

def self.download_walmart_orders(out)
    out ||= "#{Rails.root}/test_orders.csv"   
        CSV.foreach(out, :headers => true,
                  :converters => :all,
                  :header_converters => lambda { |h| h.downcase.gsub(' ', '_') }
                  ) do |row|
   geek = Geek.where(customer_order_id: row.to_h["customer_order_id"], 
                                     customer_name: row.to_h["customer_name"],
                                     item_sku: row.to_h["item_sku"],
                                     quantity_to_ship: row.to_h["quantity_to_ship"],
                                     total_items_price: row.to_h["total_items_price"]).first_or_create
    puts geek
end     
end
```

end

Comment: Sounds pretty cool. Did you have a question?

Comment: In Rails 5 you want to use [`find_or_create_by`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_create_by).

Comment: Hi jvillian, I apologize for the poor phrasing I just edited the question hoping to provide a little more clarity on my question. Hi Max - that looks like it'll work great to bring the data in if I have no updates. To an existing record. What should I use if I do in fact need to update an existing record? (Question is rephrased up top to give a better example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that `customer_order_id` is unique.

You could try something like this -

```
   def self.update_or_create(attributes)
     assign_or_new(attributes).save
   end


   Geek.where(customer_order_id: row.to_h["customer_order_id"]).update_or_create.( 
                                 customer_name: row.to_h["customer_name"],
                                 item_sku: row.to_h["item_sku"],
                                 quantity_to_ship: row.to_h["quantity_to_ship"],
                                 total_items_price: row.to_h["total_items_price"])
```

---

^^^ Thank you, Michael, for the direction above. I ended up using this code and it worked perfectly. (For a slightly different project but exact same use case) my finalized model code is below:

```
class Wheel < ApplicationRecord
require 'csv'

def self.update_or_create(attributes)
  obj = first || new
  obj.assign_attributes(attributes)
  obj.save!
end

def self.import(out)
    out ||= "#{Rails.root}/public/300-RRW Daily Inv Report.csv"
        CSV.foreach(out, :headers => true,
                  :converters => :all,
                  :header_converters => lambda { |h| h.downcase.gsub(' ', '_') }
                  ) do |row|
     Wheel.where(item: row.to_h["item"]).update_or_create(
                                     item_desc: row.to_h["item_desc"],
                                     total_quantity: row.to_h["total_quantity"])
  end
end
```

end

Comment: This definitely lead me in the right direction. Thank you, Michael, for all the help!

Comment: Glad I could help! :) Please do accept the answer if it's good to go :D